# Proof : $S$ a subspace of a vector space is generated by $n$ vectors, any $m$ vectors in $S$ , where $m > n$ are linearly dependent.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Constraints :

1. Basis and dimensions are not introduced yet
2. Matrix and system of equations can't be used

I am aware that this might possibly be a duplicate of the [same question here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2234481/if-a-subspace-s-is-spanned-by-n-vectors-any-subset-of-s-with-mn-vectors-is), but I wanted to take this question further and see if any of you have come across an alternative proof than the one mentioned in the first answer. Btw, I am new to this platform, so in case I am making a mistake by posting this, please let me know.

Comment: How would you rephrase a set generates a space? 

Comment: By further I meant, I wanted to ask if someone from the community came across a sleeker proof somewhere. I agree that better is not the most appropriate word for the question. I would just edit and put alternative in place of better. By generated the book I am going through (Curtis : Theorem 5.1) means that the space is spanned by the vectors in the set as per my understanding. Thanks for your reply though.

Comment: It does in some way. But I am looking for another proof, if it exists ofc and that's precisely is my question. And I have already linked to this question in my question itself. Thanks for your response though.

Answer (score 0):

The following proof may resemble the second answer of the linked post, but I do not fully understand the argument there.

Clearly, the assertion in the title follows from Lemma 1 below (if $v_1,\cdots,v_n$ are linearly dependent, then the space $S$ can be spanned by fewer than $n$ vectors).

**Lemma 1.** Let $v_1,\cdots,v_n$ be independent and $$S=<v_1,\cdots,v_n>.$$ Then any $n+1$ vectors in $S$ are linearly dependent.

**Lemma 2.** Assume Lemma 1 holds for $n=k-1$. Let $$S=<v_1,\cdots,v_k>,~{\rm and~}w_1,\cdots,w_k\in S,$$ where $v_1,\cdots,v_k$ (resp. $w_1,\cdots,w_k$) are linearly independent. Then $$S=<w_1,\cdots,w_k>.$$

*Proof*. Given the assumption, it suffices to show that $$S=<v_1,\cdots,v_k>=<w_i,v_2,\cdots, v_k>\quad (1)$$ for some $1\leq i\leq k$ and $w_i,v_2,\cdots,v_k$ are linearly independent. Repeating the argument, one can achieve the result by replacing all $v_i$’s by $w_i$’s up to ordering.

To prove (1), one uses the assumption that Lemma 1 holds for $n=k-1$. It follows that there exists $i$ such that $$w_i\notin ~<v_2,\cdots,v_k>,$$ since $w_1,\cdots,w_k$ are linearly independent. Now $$w_i=c_1v_1+c_2v_2+\cdots+c_kv_k~{\rm with~}c_1\neq 0,$$ hence $$v_1\in ~<w_i,v_2,\cdots,v_k>~\supseteq ~<v_1,\cdots,v_k>$$
$$\Rightarrow ~<w_i,v_2,\cdots,v_k>=<v_1,\cdots,v_k>,$$ since the other inclusion is trivial. The independence of $w_i,v_2,\cdots,v_k$ can be verified by definition. $\Box$

*Proof of Lemma 1.* One proves it by induction on $n$, the case $n=1$ being clear. Assume the case $n=k-1\geq 1$ is true. One needs to show that case for $n=k$: Namely if $S=<v_1,\cdots,v_k>$, and $v_1,\cdots,v_k$ are linearly independent, then any $k+1$ vectors $w_1,\cdots,w_k,w_{k+1}$ in $S$ are linearly dependent.

If $w_1,\cdots,w_k$ are linearly dependent, the result is clear. Hence one may assume that $w_1,\cdots,w_k$ are linearly independent. But then by Lemma 2, one has $$S=<v_1,\cdots,v_k>=<w_1,\cdots,w_k>.$$ Since $w_{k+1}\in S=<w_1,\cdots,w_k>,$ one has $$w_{k+1}=\sum_{i=1}^k c_iw_i$$ $$\Rightarrow w_1,\cdots,w_{k+1}$$ are linearly dependent. QED

Comment: What? You prove Lemma 1 using Lemma 2 and Lemma 2 using Lemma 1. Is it even legal?

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin, that does not sound logically sound.

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin Lemma 2 is a consequence of the induction hypothesis for the proof of Lemma 1. I will double check and possibly rewrite to make sure it is not confusing.

Answer (score 0):

For comparison with my previous writing, the following is a slightly different write up.

The result of the OP’s assertion follows from the following lemma. One makes sure not to use matrices, linear equations, bases, or dimension.

**Lemma**. Let $v_1,\cdots,v_n$ be independent and $$S=<v_1,\cdots,v_n>.$$ Then any $n+1$ vectors in $S$ are linearly dependent.

*Proof*. One proceeds by induction on $n$, the case $n=1$ being clear.

**(IH)** Assume that the result is true for $n=k-1\geq 1,$ i.e. if $v_1,\cdots,v_{k-1}$ are linearly independent and $T=<v_1,\cdots,v_{k-1}>.$ Then any $k$ vectors in $T$ are linearly dependent.

For $n=k$, let $v_1,\cdots,v_k$ be linearly independent and $S=<v_1,\cdots,v_k>.$ Let $w_1,\cdots,w_{k+1}\in S.$ One needs to show that $w_1,\cdots,w_{k+1}$ are linearly dependent.

**Case 1.** $w_1,\cdots,w_k$ are linearly dependent.

Clearly $w_1,\cdots,w_{k+1}$ must be linearly dependent in this case.

**Case 2.** $w_1,\cdots,w_k$ are linearly independent.

**Claim:** $S=<v_1,\cdots,v_k>=<w_1,\cdots,w_k>.$

*Proof of Claim:* It suffices to show that $$S=<v_1,\cdots,v_k>=<w_i,v_2,\cdots,v_k>$$ for some $1\leq i \leq k,$ and $w_i,v_2,\cdots,v_k$ are linearly independent. ......(1)

(Repeating the argument, one can achieve the Claim by replacing all $v_i$’s by $w_i$’s up to reordering.)

To prove (1), note that by induction hypothesis (IH) applied to $T=<v_2,\cdots,v_k>,$ one sees that not all $w_j$’s are in $T$, since $w_1,\cdots,w_k$ are linearly independent. It follows that there exists $i,1\leq i\leq k$ such that $w_i\notin T=<v_2,\cdots,v_k>.$ Now $$w_i=c_1v_1+c_2v_2+\cdots+c_kv_k~{\rm with~}c_1\neq 0,$$ hence $$v_1\in ~<w_i,v_2,\cdots,v_k>~\supseteq~<v_1,\cdots,v_k>$$
$$\Rightarrow <w_i,v_2,\cdots,v_k>=<v_1,\cdots,v_k>,$$ since the other inclusion is trivial. The independence of $w_i,v_2,\cdots,v_k$ can be verified by definition. This concludes the proof of (1), hence the Claim.

Now to finish Case 2 and show that $w_1,\cdots,w_k,w_{k+1}$ are linearly dependent, note by the Claim that $w_{k+1}\in S=<w_1,\cdots,w_k>,$ hence $$w_{k+1}=\sum_{i =1}^k c_iw_i$$ $$\Rightarrow w_1,\cdots,w_{k+1}~{\rm are ~linearly ~dependent.}$$

This concludes the proof for Case 2, and the Lemma. QED